# In my example, did I use the comma correctly?

Tags: commas

The IV cannot be randomized in this case, but randomization allows for balance between two groups, one on each side of the threshold.

Maybe the sentence I just wrote below is better?

> The IV cannot be randomized in this case. Randomization allows for
>   balance between two groups, one on each side of the threshold. I
>   believe both groups are very similar except for drinking and death
>   rate. Thus, I believe assumption 1 is met.

Comment: I think I'd want to rephrase, but I'd like a couple of extra sentences for context. (Is the main point of this sentence to tell us that the IV cannot be randomized in this case, or is it to tell us about the benefits of randomization?)

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that more clear.

Comment: Now I don't understand the thrust of the context! However, your new sentence 'Randomization allows for balance between two groups, one on each side of the threshold.' is grammatically fine and the comma is essential.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this usage is correct. Your second example does a better job of showing why:

> Randomization allows for balance between two groups, one on each side of the threshold.

If you removed the comma:

> Randomization allows for balance between two groups one on each side of the threshold.

The two clauses merge and the sentence becomes meaningless.